# UIPopOverController with segment controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uipopovercontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

How can i show the segmentcontroller in `UIPopOverController` like in this picture,PLs refer me any code?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have done this by the following code.
I have added an `IBAction` for a button and added the following code, it worked perfectly for me.

```
- (IBAction)Test:(id)sender
{
    UISegmentedControl *segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three", nil]];
    UIViewController *tempView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    tempView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 44);
    [tempView.view addSubview:segment];
    pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tempView];
    pop.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(180, 44);
    [pop presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 44) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
}
```

Here `pop` is `UIPopoverController` declared in the @`interface`.

Comment: its showing error `'-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'`

Comment: You cannot show popover on Iphone, please refer apple's docs.

Answer (score 0):

That's a standard menu that appears in a `UITextField` or `UITextView`. You don't have to write any code to get that menu in your own text fields or text views. Just tap in the text field or text view on the same location as the cursor or double-tap to select some text and the menu will appear automatically.

Comment: i want to know how to make this in our app

Answer (score 0):

Try with this [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover). You can use this and add your segment controller inside that. You might have to customize the appearance of segmentcontroller for this kind of look and feel.

Comment: what change should i made here to incude uisegment controler in the WEPopover code 
  `UIViewController *contentViewController = [[WEPopoverContentViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
  
  self.popoverController = [[[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController] autorelease];
  [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame 
            inView:self.view 
         permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
             animated:YES];`